# If $M$ is a real symmetric matrix such that $M^{k}=0$ for $k \in N$ then $M=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

My attempt :
$M$ is a real symmetric matrix so $PMP^{-1}=D$ for some $D$ being a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix.Now, $PM^kP^{-1}=D^k$.So we see that $M^k$ is also similar to a diagonal matrix and $D^k=0$, (as $M^k=0$)so $D=0$.If $D$ is a zero matrix then $M=P^{-1}DP$ from here we can conclude that $M=0$.

Is my reasoning OK?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is absolutely correct.
You can see;

$D^k=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^k &0&0\\ 0&\lambda_2^k&0\\0&0&\lambda_3^k\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore $D^k=0 \iff D=0$(provided $D$ is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: Just commenting that the OP's proof generalizes to the case where $M$ is diagonalizable (over any field).